# Cannot access WHM and SSH/root after a configuration in Host Access Control

Tags: linux, ip, cpanel

I added my IP (like 172.32.1.0/255.255.255.0) to allow access for `ssh`, `whm` and `cpanel` in WHM -> Host Access Control. Then, I added all IP to deny access for them. However, after saved changes, I lost access all of them. Now, If I try to login WHM, I see that:

> **HTTP error 401**
>
> You do not have permission to access this page.

Also, I cannot access SSH. I don't know what to do. If I restart server, will the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally lock yourself out of WHM, edit the /etc/hosts.allow file through the command line to regain access.

You must enter your allow rules before your deny rules. For example, if you choose to allow access for two IP addresses, but you want to deny access from all other addresses, you can use either of the following methods:

Create two separate rules:

Create one rule that allows 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
Create a second rule that denies access to ALL IP addresses.

Or, Create one rule:

Enter all except 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 in the Access List text box.
Enter denyin the Action text box.

**Server restart won't solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, I didn't deny my IP address accidentally. First I allowed mine and then denied all others but interestingly it blocked my IP address. So, I cannot edit the file you metioned because I cannot access SSH like WHM.